# Installing Gemstash onto Jenkins Slave

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to cache ruby gems onto a Jenkins slave. I have installed gemstash onto my linux virtualbox which runs the slave, but however, I am not sure if I am installing it in the right location. 
Should I be installing it by logging into the Jenkins user in the terminal and installing it there? Because when I created the slave node, I didn't need to install Jenkins onto the box. The source I use for the gemfile is `localhost:9292`

EDIT: 
And how can I check what packages gemstash has cached? 
Checking if gemstash has cached packages can be done by following https://github.com/bundler/gemstash#bundling

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the [README](https://github.com/bundler/gemstash#under-the-hood) says, have a look in `~/.gemstash`:

> You might wonder where the gems are stored. After running the commands above, you will find a new directory at ~/.gemstash. This directory holds all the cached and private gems. It also has a server log, the database, and configuration for Gemstash.

Comment: Thanks. I was not getting any gems cached when I had ran the Gemfile. But turns out I missed out on `bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org http://localhost:9292`.